# Missing and unexpected chars in reading a large input stream using BufferedInputStream in java

Tags: java

I have to do  read an Large InputStream comming from a URL. 
I loaded the InputStream to the **BufferedInputStream** and read it to a **byte[ ]** and I append that byte [] to a StringBuilder converting it to a string. After all data has been appended to the StringBuilder, the resulting String contains some missing and unexpected chars. I didn't use any encoding (Eg. UTF-8) here since the response is coming in the similar format I expected.

Can you give any suggestions to solve this?

**Code :**

```
    BufferedInputStream brIn    = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    StringBuilder response      = new StringBuilder(1000);

    byte[] byteBfr  = new byte[8192];
    int n=0;

    while((n=brIn.read(byteBfr,0,byteBfr.length)) != -1){
        response.append(new String(byteBfr).toCharArray(),0,n);
    }

    return  response.toString();
```

**Output :**
This is a part of the resulting response. The complete one contains about 554595 lines.

*Expected Result :*

```
  <Hotel>
    <CiID>31</CiID>
    <HoID>58617</HoID>
    <Name>HARRY΄S</Name>
    <Address>PROTARAS</Address>
    <Phone>00357 23 834100</Phone>
    <Fax>0035723831860</Fax>
    <Stars>3</Stars>
  </Hotel>
```

*Actual Result :*

```
  <Hotel>
    <CiID>31</CiID>
    <HoID>58617</HoID>
    <Name>HARRY΄S</Name>
    <Address>PROTARAS</AdAdress>
 <   <Phone>00357 23 834100</Phone>
    <Fa9x>00390<P654224546</Fax>
    <Stars>3</Stars>
  </Hotel>
```

In the above one you can see the unexpected chars in the Address, Fax and in the Phone.

Comment: give an example of what is your expected value and the actual value

Comment: And show us the actual code. That would definitely help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're reading in the entire string at once (as opposed to processing it as it arrives), consider using a **BufferedReader**.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class UrlReading {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String inputLine;
    while( (inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(reader.readLine());
    }
  }
}
```

Alternately, if you're reading in xml, consider using a solution that will let you parse the xml, like:

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse("http://google.com");
```

Comment: 1.Actually, the BufferedReader was my first try. Since the input stream is comming as Binarry Data array I Used this BufferedInputStream for the efficiency. And  after the response is built completely I used a SAXParser to manipulate the xml.That part is Ok. The problem is with getting and building the complete response that contains over 554595 lines of xml befor parse to the SAXParser.

Comment: Have you tested that the data is correct over the network? If you fetch it via wget or curl, and view it in hex, does it match what you have at the source? Is the source converting to binary data for any reason (or do you have control over the source)? If it's for efficiency, consider a gzipped xml.

Comment: Yes I tested that the data is correct over the network. There is no issue with the network. The source send me the output as binary data

Comment: you can call append(String) instead of converting to a char array, and could try using a StringBuffer instead of a StringBuilder (it'll be faster). I'm not sure why this would fix your issue, but it's worth a try. Can you print out the strings as you build them (new String(byteBfr) ) to see if that's where the string's getting corrupted?

Comment: Ok Thank you very much. I'll try it. I used StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer since I'm not using the treads here (StringBuilder is not sync and StringBuffer is sync. So, StringBuffer would be faster when they are used in the threads).

Comment: Using Streams will only work if the data in question is only 1 byte per character. If you hit data that is mult-byte it will fail, which is why the suggestion to use Readers is relevant.

Comment: Normally, in java a character takes two bytes. That's means must I use BufferReader Anyway?

Comment: It depends what the input is. You said above that it is binary. In that case you shouldn't be converting it to a String at all, you should be managaint it as a byte[] array. If it really is character data you should use a Reader. What you're doing at the moment is six of one and half-a-dozen of the other.